# Let $l$ be a natural number. Prove that $n\lt\sqrt{n ^ 2 + l}\lt n+1$ for almost every $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification

In my assignment I have to prove the following statement:

> Let $l$ be a natural number. Prove that for almost every $n$ the following inequality is true: $$n\lt\sqrt{n ^ 2 + l}\lt n+1$$

I chose to prove this by contradiction, and I wanted to know if it's correct.

- It is obvious that $n \lt n+1$.
- Assume for the sake of contradiction that $n \ge \sqrt{n ^ 2 + l}$.

  Squaring both sides, we get:
  $$
     \begin{align}
     n^2 &\ge n^2 + l \\
     0 &\ge l
     \end{align}
     $$
  which contradicts the fact that $l$ is natural. Therefore, $n \lt \sqrt{n ^ 2 + l}$.
- Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\sqrt{n ^ 2 + l} \ge n+1$.

  Squaring both sides, we get:
  $$
     \begin{align}
     n^2+l &\ge n^2+2n+1 \\
     l &\ge 2n+1
     \end{align}
     $$
  but this is another contradiction, because $l$ is a constant number, and can't be bigger than an infinite amount of numbers.

Therefore the inequality $n\lt\sqrt{n ^ 2 + l}\lt n+1$ is true.

Is my solution correct?

Thank you,

Alan

Comment: `can't be bigger than an infinite amount of numbers.' is not a phrase you want to see in a proof. The idea is there though

Comment: @JackYoon thank you, I am very glad to hear that. Can you be more specific about the idea I have to improve there?

Comment: Search for $n$ such that which the inequality definitely hold.

Comment: Let's say I choose n to be bigger than $2n+1$. Then for almost every n, it's bigger than this $l$, and we have a contradiction?

Comment: Contradiction does not seem like a good idea for this question to be honest. It can be made correct but the argument you have to make to prove by contradiction is exactly same as trying to prove it directly.

Comment: So you should aim to find infinitely many $n$ such that the inequality hold. And such criterion is easily found from the 'calculation' you have already done so far.

Comment: Minor point: consider using a letter other than $l$ for a variable, looks too much like $1$.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte thank you, it is an important point!

Answer (score 1):

$$l\geq 2n+1$$ This doesn't contradict a known fact. It just states a boundary for $l$ given your assumption is correct. In a proof by contradiction, you need to arrive at results contradicting a general result for all $n$. Also $\sqrt {n^2+l}<n+1$ isn't true for all $n$, given an $l$. In fact, it is true only for $n>{\dfrac{l-1}{2}}$

To prove the inequality, you can simply say that it holds for all $n>{\dfrac{l-1}{2}}$, which will also satisfy the phrase "for almost every $n$".

Comment: Thank you. I see what is wrong, how do I make it right?

Comment: Let's say I choose n to be bigger than $2n+1$. Then for almost every n, it's bigger than this $l$, and we have a contradiction?

Comment: @Alan, the answer has been edited. Hope it is clear now. (It had a small mistake earlier)

Comment: thank you! I'll have a look.